# What is the best monitoring solution for open source cassandra clusters.?

Tags: cassandra

If we have open source Cassandra cluster what are the best monitoring platform to address the cluster monitoring needs.?

As Datastax ops center removed the support for Open Source Cassandra Clusters from 6.0 onwards, we want to look at other options.

Netflix priam provides REST API, but it will not have UI. I have found few examples that are integrating cassandra cluster with ELK and Graphite, but would like to know what is the best in this regard

Comment: As of now, I couldn't find anything for this. Datastax recently removed the support for OSS Cassandra, so it might be some time before we see any serious competition for Datastax OpsCenter

Answer (score 1):

One option for monitoring is prometheus (maybe with grafana as a nicer frontent)
Have a look at this post: http://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-cassandra-with-prometheus/

You'd have to install jmx exporter for prometheus on each node and of course prometheus itself. With that you can export all the jmx metrics which are exposed by cassandra (see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Metrics). The jmx exporter will start a http endpoint from which prometheus can collect the metrics.

This however will only be useful for monitoring, not for operating

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention another option here, you can use Nagios to monitor Cassandra, a good starting point tutorial for monitoring and maintaining 'DataStax Enterprise or Apache Cassandra' is [here](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/diagnosing-problems-production-datastax-enterprise-and-apache-cassandra)

Answer (score 0):

If want to store in C* can look at http://cyanite.io/ with the cassandra graphite reporter and grafana.

Comment: can use graphite reporter (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2) to push to cyanite (or graphite)

Answer (score -1):

I am a member of the team working on http://selectstar.io which is capable of providing monitoring-as-a-service for OSS Cassandra clusters as well as quite a few other databases.

Please take a look.  We are building out new features quickly and would love your feedback.

Comment: we need an opensource solution!